# Why doesn't the while loop run once again?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, binary

I tried to write binary expression for decimal numbers. Here is my code:

```
value=0.375
result=""
while(value<1):
    value*=2
    if(value>=1):
        value-=1
        result+=str(1)
        break
    result+=str(0)
print(result)
```

**Output : 01** but must be **011**

*I wanted to run while loop once more by decreasing value by one but it seems doesn't work.*

Comment: Your "break" should be a "continue".  You're telling the loop to stop as soon as you output your first 1.

Comment: Actually, why is your termination statement `value < 1`?  That seems sort of off, too.  You should continue running until value == 1 or you've generated a certain number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct logic:

```
ENOUGH_PRECISION = 20             # Enough number of 1's and 0's in the output
value=0.3753453856869
result=""
while(value<1):
    value*=2
    if(value>=1):
        value-=1
        result+=str(1)
    else:
        result+=str(0)
    if len(result) == ENOUGH_PRECISION:
        break
print(result)
```

**Output:**

> 01100000000101101010